# owl carousel not work with bootstrap RTL 3( Arabic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I added [owl carousel](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel) in my project with [bootstrap 3 arabic](https://github.com/zeroxme/bootstrap-3-arabic) like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="owl-carousel">
                <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=1" data-src-retina="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=1-retina">
                <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=2" data-src-retina="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=2-retina">
                <!-- other images -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10
});
```

But owl carousel does NOT work with Arabic bootstrap and does NOT show any image.
How can I fix this problem ?

[fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/55Lomf4v/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add option - `rtl:true`

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/rtl.html

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6ef5p1u1/18/

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 4,
  lazyLoad: true,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  rtl: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://servu.besaba.com/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=1" data-src-retina="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=1-retina" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=2" data-src-retina="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=2-retina" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=3" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=4" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=5" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=6" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=7" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=8" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=9" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=10" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://placehold.it/350x250&text=11" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear friend you can put the following piece of code instead of "owl.carousel.css" until the problem is resolved.

```css
/* 
 *  Core Owl Carousel CSS File
 * v1.3.3
 */

/* clearfix */
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 height: 0;
}
/* display none until init */
.owl-carousel{
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
 float: left;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 width: 200%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{
 -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
 transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
 
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
 float: left;
}
.owl-controls .owl-page,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* mouse grab icon */
.grabbing { 
    cursor:url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}

/* fix */
.owl-carousel  .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel  .owl-item{
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
 -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can set **autoPlay : true**

To make image slideshow, there are many options (plugins) that you can use :

- Bootstrap Carousel
- Using Wowslider
- Flexslider
- Coinslider

[Detailed Technology Center](https://ilmu-detil.blogspot.co.id/2016/04/membuat-carousel-headline-news-berjalan.html)

Answer (score 0):

This what solved the problem, applying the `dir` attribute on the `div` which contains the element which your javascript will work on

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-6" dir="ltr">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <!-- your html -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code of the javascript need not to be modified

[Github issue](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/643)

Answer (score 0):

You can Just replace these styles on owl.carousel.css

```
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    float: left;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item{
    float: left;
}
```